# Error when delete comment Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

When I delete comment I see

> ***undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass***

Also, the user cannot delete his account if has posted... It makes the error.

This is code

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Comments</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Link</th>
      <th>Body</th>
      <th>User</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @comments.each do |comment| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= comment.link_id %></td>
        <td><%= comment.body %></td>
        <td><%= comment.user %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', comment %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_comment_path(comment) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', comment, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Comment', new_comment_path %>
```

Comment: Can you share the code for your `CommentsController`? More specifically, the destroy action.

Comment: please share your controller code as well. It will help us more to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your are not checking if any comments are present before looping through them.  So if there are no comments you are calling `each` on nil.

This should fix it

```
<tbody>
   <% if @comments.any? %> <----- Add in this line and the end below
    <% @comments.each do |comment| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= comment.link_id %></td>
        <td><%= comment.body %></td>
        <td><%= comment.user %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', comment %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_comment_path(comment) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', comment, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  <% end %> <---- here
</tbody>
```

Comment: I know I'm making assumptions, but depending on how you've written the controller, `@comments` should at least be an empty collection, right? That way you don't need the check (unless you wanted to display an empty message of some sort).

Comment: Hard to say, my guess is it is `@comments = Comment.all` or is related to posts in which case I think this is a likely culprit to produce the error, it is an assumption on my part to though.